# Is it possible to run two copies of Mac application with different plist files?

Tags: mac, filesystems, plist

I am trying to run two versions of the `Messages` app on OSX with two different user accounts. I can easily copy/paste the `.app` file and run the app as two different processes, but since they use the same plist and database, they have the same accounts/data (here's a good list of files it creates: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/107120/62420)

Is it possible to modify the storage location of one or more of the apps? Can I run the app in such a way that when it requests file access, I can modify the true file location of the file it requests? For example, if it requests `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.imservice.iMessage.plist` can I redirect that to `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.imservice.iMessage2.plist` using the process name or id?

Comment: Never tried it with a Apple app, but generally you can only do that kind of trick before compile... so I'd say you're out of luck.

Comment: chroot jail should work for you

Answer (score 1):

I think, that it is not possible to redirect process to another file by it's id or something, but if you want to have more accounts simultaneously, you can create new user and associate different Apple ID to it and then switch between accounts.

> Apple suggests **keeping separate computer accounts** to handle multiple
> users on a single computer.
>
> You could, of course, set up an **additional user account** for her so
> that her iMessage account settings are distinct from yours.

---

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87062/multiple-apple-id-in-messages-app
- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5522742?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible because codesigning was introduced in OSX  to prevent tampering with apps. The plist is part of the bundle, therefore part of the signing by the developer.

[code signing in depth](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2206/_index.html)

The Info.plist within the app bundle defines configuration that is not embedded in the binary [see bundle structure](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW1) . The bundle id relates to the preference files it can write. Since the bundle id is part of the app, and therefore signed, you cannot create an alternative preference file.

You could jump through hoops and try to mount and symlink other filesystems to swap these file between launching 2 instances of the app, but I doubt you would accept the risks of this on a daily basis.

Comment: Won’t take no for an answer?

Comment: These files are not inside the bundle, but in your home directory

Comment: The info plist that tells the OS what the app is, is inside the bundle; open one & see. If you don't save any edits, you won't break the signature, if you do you may [I'm no developer, but i've messed about with this stuff before... & failed, even by compiling my own version & changing internals - I could get the app to form an independent folder/prefs structure, but I couldn't make it read/write to it.